# Python Support missing from NeoVim

Tags: linux, debian, neovim

I have installed neovim from the official source using the appimage method
Here's the link for that [Official installation instructions](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim)

after doing all my config settings , i went to apply my config settings. which were followed from my .vimrc. After installing all plugins it said , python support missing.
[image: Python support missing]

After all research,i couldn't find any solution. and now here's my `nvim +checkhealth`

[image: checkhealth]

These were the main reason i upgraded to neovim, including the clipboard support . my vim had python3 support , but missing on neovim.

I am on a ubuntu machine. and installed it with appimage.

Comment: There are answers for your question. You should provide feed whether the answer works for you or not.

Comment: It looks like this question was closed. I guess you could ask it on https://vi.stackexchange.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure python is set on your $PATH properly.
Set this in your .vimrc or init.lua:

```lua
let g:python3_host_prog = 'path/to/python3'
let g:python2_host_prog = 'path/to/python2'
```

Lua equivalent:

```lua
vim.g.python3_host_prog = 'path/to/python3'
vim.g.python2_host_prog = 'path/to/python2'
```

Install pynvim: `bash pip3 install pynvim`
This should resolve the lack of python support.

There's more information regarding the reasoning of the requirements in the `:help provider-python` manual if you're interested.

Comment: I use windows here, So just asking, Do I use the path to the exe or the path to the folder python is in or the path to the folder the exe is in?

Comment: It does not work with Python 3.10 and neovim 0.8.3. Pythons is there but neovim does not detect it.

Comment: @ShauryaChhabra Sorry for the delay :'). I can't debug this on windows but I assume it's the path to the python exe file.